How to enlarge or make sure the maximum AVAssetWriter Input frame size?
I try to write frames into a video using AVAssetWriter. I wrote codes as below:
// Initial AVAssetWriter
// Write mp4 file
let assetWriter = try AVAssetWriter(outputURL: targetUrl, fileType: .mp4)
let width = size.width * 2
// set options for written video
let videoSettings: [String : Any] = [
    AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecType.h264,
    AVVideoWidthKey: width,
    AVVideoHeightKey: size.height
]
guard assetWriter.canApply(outputSettings: videoSettings, forMediaType: AVMediaType.video) else {
    fatalError("Error applying output settings")
}
// Initial AVAssetWriterInput
let assetWriterInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: .video, outputSettings: videoSettings)

// set arritbutes
let sourcePixelBufferAttributes: [String : Any] = [
    kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA]

// Initial AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor
let inputPixelBufferAdaptor = 
    AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor(assetWriterInput: assetWriterInput,
                                         sourcePixelBufferAttributes: sourcePixelBufferAttributes)
if assetWriter.canAdd(assetWriterInput) == true {
    assetWriter.add(assetWriterInput)
    assetWriter.startWriting()
    assetWriter.startSession(atSourceTime: .zero)
} else {
    print("Cannot add asset writer input.")
}

if let error = assetWriter.error {
    print("assetWrite status=\(assetWriter.status), error=\(error)")
}

But using my iPhone 14 Pro, it will run into print("assetWrite status=\(assetWriter.status), error=\(error)") shows:
assetWrite status=AVAssetWriterStatus(rawValue: 3), error=Error 
Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could not be completed" 
UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-12902), 
NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed, NSUnderlyingError=0x30189cb10 
{Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12902 "(null)"}}

The size = CGSize(width: 2200, height: 2200) that is width = size.width * 2 = 4400
If I wrote:
let videoSettings: [String : Any] = [
    AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecType.h264,
    AVVideoWidthKey: 4090, // width,
    AVVideoHeightKey: size.height
]

It won't run into the error. If set as 4100 or larger will also run into the error.
Is there anyway to solve this issue that using the 4400 or larger value as the width key?

Understanding the error message is crucial:  Error  Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could not be completed"  UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-12902),
-12902(which is kVTParameterErr) typically means your parameters passed to AssertWriter(VideoToolbox under the hood) is wrong.
So, check the logs from the console you can get a better understanding:

The H264StartSession first says your resolution is within the acceptable range of the H.264 encoder [4400,2208], slightly larger than standard 4k 4096x2160 in H.264 Level 5.1.
However, this doesn't necessarily mean that subsequent modules support the resolution. The H.264 standard technically supports resolutions up to 8192x4320 (Level 6.2), but many devices and software implementations do not support these higher levels. The most commonly supported maximum resolution for H.264 is 4096x2160 (Level 5.1). The FigExportCommon module, which I believe is the hardware-accelerated media exporting system on iOS implemented with VideoToolbox, does not accept any dimension larger than 4096x4096. Interesting, I see NV also has this limitation:

Nvidia RTX3060 is the Ampere architecture with 7th gen NVENC for encoding H.264 and H.265. Its H.264 encoding capabilities max out at 4096x4096. If Resolve is set to use the Nvidia hardware encoder it can't encode to a higher resolution than that. It's 8192x8192 for H.265.

I created a demo project here, you can fiddle with it and you can see if your dimension is larger than 4096x4096, a kVTParameterErr will occur.
If you really want a dimension like 4400x2200, consider changing AVVideoCodecKey to AVVideoCodecType.hevc, it works. I believe at the year of 2024, HEVC(H.265) is also wildly supported.

It is a memory issue try using autoreleasepool
let pxBuffer = autoreleasepool {return self.newPixelBufferFrom(cgImage: image.cgImage!)}

The above code does not generate a pixelbuffer yet, so I am not sure how to do what you posted.
